# Wordpress - if the content conditional hides section tag parent of the_content() call

Tags: php, html, wordpress

All I want to do is simply render a `<section>` tag that contains the output of `the_content()` function in Wordpress:

```
<?php if (the_content()): ?>
    <section class="page-content">
        <?php the_content() ?>
    </section>
<?php endif ?>
```

This for whatever reason *does not* work and *only* renders my content and *not* my section tag. Why?

```
<section class="page-content">
    <?php if (the_content()): ?>
        <?php the_content() ?>
    <?php endif ?> 
</section>
```

This works but I don't want to render an empty section tag when theres no content.

How do you conditionally render `the_content()` with a wrapping section tag without it disappearing? Why does it hide when I do it the first way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) always performs an `echo`. If you look at the source from the previous link, however, you'll see that the first thing that it does is call another function called [`get_the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) which returns and doesn't echo.

So you can change your code to this:

```php
<?php $theContent = get_the_content(); ?>
<?php if ($theContent): ?>
    <section class="page-content">
        <?php echo $theContent ?>
    </section>
<?php endif ?>
```

Unfortunately, `the_content` also calls a filter that you might need and does an additional edge-case clean up. You can fix this in one of two ways:

1. Mix both `the_content` and `get_the_content`. Technically you are doing double-work but it probably isn't too much of an issue, and if you have caching enabled it shouldn't matter.

```php
<?php if (get_the_content()): ?>
    <section class="page-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </section>
<?php endif ?>
```

2. Use the same filter logic as core:

```php
<?php $theContent = get_the_content(); ?>
<?php if ($theContent): ?>
    <?php $theContent = apply_filters( 'the_content', $theContent );  ?>
    <?php $theContent = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $theContent );  ?>
    <section class="page-content">
        <?php echo $theContent; ?>
    </section>
<?php endif ?>
```